# Average difference between actual and expected per number of events

Tags: probability, dice

Given that a dice is tossed $N$ times, how much is the ratio between the most occurred number and the less occurred number on average (given that I repeat this N tossing a very large number of times) ?

This ratio tends to 1 as the number of throws  N tends to infinity.

But given N how can I get the average ratio of most occurred / least occurred?

Here is an experimental graph of this relation (the tossing of N dice was not repeated hence the "wobbly" nature of the grapph):

[image: Graph]

Code:

```
import random

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = [ 1 for _ in range(6) ]

def update_results(results):
    die_toss = random.randint(0, 5)
    return [x + (1 if i == die_toss else 0) for i, x in enumerate(results)]+

def plot_points(ps):
    plt.scatter(*zip(*ps))

ps = []
for i in range(1,10000):
    x = update_results(x)
    ps.append( (i, max(x) / float(min(x)) ) )
    #ps.append( (i, max(x) / (i*(1./6)) ) )

plot_points(ps)
plt.xlabel('Number of dice throws')
plt.ylabel('Most occured / Least Occured Ratio')
plt.show()
```

Comment: how did u generate this graph?

Comment: Won't the distribution depend on your pseudo-random generator?

Comment: @Abhijith The pseudo random generator is assumed to be perfectly random for this purpose

Comment: @Kiran code added

Answer (score 2):

This is  revealed to  be more difficult  than it  looks but we  can at
least provide  an algorithm  to compute the  exact values  rather than
rely on simulations.

Suppose that the  die has $m$ faces and is  rolled $n$ times.  Rolling
the die  with the least occured  value being $p$ and  the most occured
value being $q$ and both of them marked yields the species

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=m}
(\mathfrak{P}_{=0}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{=p}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathfrak{P}_{=p+1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots
+ \mathfrak{P}_{=q-1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{V}\mathfrak{P}_{=q}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This has generating function

$$G(z,u,v) =
\left(1+u\frac{z^p}{p!} + \sum_{r=p+1}^{q-1} \frac{z^r}{r!}
+ v\frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^m.$$

Subtracting the values where sets of size $p$ and $q$ did not occur we
obtain the generating function

$$H_{p,q}(z) = 
\left(1+ \sum_{r=p}^{q} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^m \\
- \left(1+ \sum_{r=p+1}^{q} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^m
- \left(1+ \sum_{r=p}^{q-1} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^m
+ \left(1+ \sum_{r=p+1}^{q-1} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^m.$$

We then obtain for the desired quantity the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n!}{m^n} 
[z^n] \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{q=p}^n \frac{q}{p} H_{p,q}(z).}$$

Introducing

$$L_{p,q}(z) = 
\left(1+ \sum_{r=p}^{q} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^m$$

we thus have

$$\frac{n!}{m^n} 
[z^n] \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{q=p}^n 
\frac{q}{p} (L_{p,q}(z)
-L_{p+1,q}(z)-L_{p,q-1}(z)+L_{p+1, q-1}(z)).$$

This is

$$\frac{n!}{m^n} 
[z^n] \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{q=p}^n 
L_{p,q}(z)\left(\frac{q}{p}
-\frac{q}{p-1}-\frac{q+1}{p}+\frac{q+1}{p-1}\right)^*$$

where the star  indicates that those terms with  $p-1=0$ and $q+1=n+1$
do not contribute. We also have for $p\lt q$

$$[z^n] L_{p,q}(z)
= [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}
\left(1+ \sum_{r=p+1}^{q} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^{m-k}
\left(\frac{z^p}{p!}\right)^k
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k} [z^{n-pk}] \frac{1}{p!^k} 
\left(1+ \sum_{r=p+1}^{q} \frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^{m-k}.$$

Furthermore we obtain for $p=q$

$$[z^n] L_{q,q}(z)
= [z^n] \left(1+ \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^m
= [[n \bmod q\equiv 0]]
\times {m\choose n/q} \frac{1}{q!^{n/q}}.$$

With these we can implement a recursion, which in fact is not all that
much faster than working  with $H_{p,q}(z).$ This yields the following
graph where  we have  used a six-sided  die. We reach  resource limits
fairly quickly (esp. space) but we do have the **exact** values for up
to $120$  rolls, which is  completely impossible by  enumeration ($94$
digits total case count). The  convergence is very slow which tells us
that we must  deploy probabilistic methods to make  progress with this
problem.

```
4.5+
   |              HH
   +             H  HH
   +            H     H
   +            H      H
   |           H        H
   +                     H
  4+          H          H
   |                      H
   +         H             H
   +                        H
   +         H              H
   |                         H
   +                          H
3.5+        H                  H
   +                           HH
   |                             H
   +       H                      H
   +                              H
   +                               HH
   |      H                          H
  3+                                 HH
   +                                   HH
   +      H                             HH
   |                                      HH
   +                                       HH
   +     H                                   HH
2.5+                                          HHH
   |                                             HH
   +                                               HHH
   +    H                                             HHH
   |                                                     HHHH
   +                                                         HHHH
   +   H                                                         HHHHHH
  2+                                                                  HHHHHHH
   |                                                                        HHHHHHHH
   +                                                                                HHHHHHHHHH
   +                                                                                          H
   +  H
   |
   +
1.5+
   +  H
   |
   +
   +
   +
   |
  1+HH
  -+--+---+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
   0              20             40             60             80             100            120
```

This was the Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(n, m)
option remember;
local rolls, res, ind, counts;
    res := 0;

    for ind from m^n to 2*m^n-1 do
        rolls := convert(ind, base, m);

        counts := map(mel->op(2, mel), 
                      convert(rolls[1..n], `multiset`));

        res := res + max(counts)/min(counts);
    od;

    res/m^n;
end;

L := (m, rmin, rmax) -> (1 + add(z^r/r!, r=rmin..rmax))^m;

X :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local H;

    H := (p, q) ->
    expand(L(m, p,q)
           - L(m, p+1,q) - L(m, p,q-1)
           + L(m, p+1,q-1));

    n!/m^n*
    coeff(add(add(q/p*H(p,q), q=p..n), p=1..n),
         z, n);
end;

LCF :=
proc(n,m,p,q)
    option remember;

    if n < 0 then return 0 fi;

    if p = q then
        if n mod q <> 0 then return 0 fi;
        return binomial(m,n/q)/q!^(n/q);
    fi;

    add(binomial(m,k)*1/p!^k*LCF(n-p*k, m-k, p+1, q),
        k=0..m);
end;

LVERIF :=
(m, p,q)  -> add(LCF(n, m, p, q)*z^n, n=0..q*m);

XX :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local res, p, q, cf;

    res := 0;

    for p to n do
        for q from p to n do
            cf := q/p
            - `if`(p>1, q/(p-1), 0)
            - `if`(q<n, (q+1)/p, 0)
            + `if`(p>1 and q<n, (q+1)/(p-1), 0);

            res := res + cf*LCF(n, m, p, q);
        od;
    od;

    res*n!/m^n;
end;
```

**Addendum.** A  rather fascinating  sequence appears when  we compute
the value  $n$ of the  number of  rolls of a  die with $m$  sides that
maximizes  the average  ratio between  most  and least.   We obtain  a
sequence that might well be linear, or it might not, here it is:

$$1, 5, 9, 13, 16, 20, 24, 28, 33, 37, 41, 46, 50, 
\\ 55, 60, 64, 69, 74, \ldots $$

A linear fit to this sequence is given by

$$- 4.82352941176471806+ 4.27966976264189913\,m.$$

This  pattern  does seem  to  suggest  the  problem merits  additional
investigation. I  hope these data  and the conjecture as  to suspected
linearity will be a start.

```
MX :=
proc(m)
    option remember;
    local n, cur, nxt;

    if m = 1 then return 1 fi;

    n := 1;
    cur := XX(1, m);

    do
        nxt := XX(n+1, m);

        if cur > nxt then
            break;
        fi;

        n := n+1;
        cur := nxt;
    od;

    n;
end;
```

**Remark.** There is a better recurrence at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114174/).

Comment: Very nice! (+1)